# JavaScript - more concise way to grab string between two characters in URL?

Tags: javascript

Is there a more concise or more standard way to grab a string between the last slash and query question mark of a URL than this?

```
const recordId= window.location.href.split("item/")[1].split("?")[0]
```

In this case I'm using `item/` because my URLs are always:

mysite.com/item/**recordIdIwantToGrab**?foo=bar&life=42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve with `URL` class in javascript.

```js
let url = 'http://example.com/item/recordIdIwantToGrab?foo=bar&life=42';
url = new URL(url);
let result = url.pathname.split('/').at('-1');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression can do the trick - match a `/`, followed by word characters, up until a `?`.

```js
const str = 'mysite.com/item/recordIdIwantToGrab?foo=bar&life=42';
const result = str.match(/\/(\w+)\?/)[1];
console.log(result);
```

- `\/` - match a literal `/`
- `(\w+)` - capturing group, match word characters
- `\` - match a literal `?`
- `[1]` - extract the value matched by the capturing group

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result using [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```js
const str = `mysite.com/item/recordIdIwantToGrab?foo=bar&life=42`;
const result = str.slice(str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, str.indexOf("?"));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think it will give bad result if user use `/` in the query. Eg: `mysite.com/item/recordIdIwantToGrab?foo=b/ar&life=42`